Add GPS to UIImage C# MAUI
Good afternoon I create and save a UIImage to the application folder on ios. I have a photo geolocated and need to save the photo with it, but I can't find information anywhere on how to do this. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
my code for creating image and saving:
public class ScreenshotService : IScreenshotService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Incoming frame
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] imageArray { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Frame width
    /// </summary>
    public int width { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Frame height
    /// </summary>
    public int height { get; set; }
    public bool serviceLock { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// File name for saving the screenshot
    /// </summary>
    private string fileName = "";
    /// <summary>
    /// Geotag
    /// </summary>
    public Location location { get; set; }

    //---------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a photo
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="view"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task<byte[]> CaptureAsync(View view)
    {
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Permission();
                // Convert color space
                var imageArgb = ConvertRgbaToArgb(imageArray, height, width);
                // Create CGDataProvider from byte array
                CGDataProvider dataProvider = new CGDataProvider(imageArgb, 0, imageArgb.Length);
                // Create CGImage from CGDataProvider
                CGImage cgImage = new CGImage(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGBitmapFlags.PremultipliedFirst | CGBitmapFlags.ByteOrder32Big, dataProvider, null, false, CGColorRenderingIntent.Default);
                // Create UIImage from CGImage
                UIImage imageBase = new UIImage(cgImage);
                // Create a renderer for this view
                var handler = view.Handler as IPlatformViewHandler;
                var nativeView = handler?.PlatformView as UIView;
                if (nativeView == null) return;
                // Calculate the size of the view
                var size = nativeView.Bounds.Size;
                // Start a new graphics context based on bitmap
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
                // Get the current graphics context
                var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
                // Render the view's layer in the current graphics context
                nativeView.Layer.RenderInContext(context);
                // Get the UIImage representation of the current graphics context
                var imageOverlay = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                // End the graphics context based on bitmap
                UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
                // Start a new graphics context based on bitmap with the image size
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(imageBase.Size, false, 0.0f);
                // Draw the base image on the new context
                imageBase.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, imageBase.Size.Width, imageBase.Size.Height));
                // Draw the overlay image on the new context
                imageOverlay.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, imageBase.Size.Width, imageBase.Size.Height));
                // Get the UIImage image from the current graphics context
                UIImage resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                // End the graphics context based on bitmap
                UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
                // Set up the output file name
                SetupOutputFileName();
                // Save the image in JPEG format
                try
                {
                    resultImage.AsJPEG().Save(fileName, false, out _);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error saving image: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------

I tried this method, but it didn't work. In the line
destination.AddImage(cgImageTest, metadata); 

gives an error that
Incorrect number or types of arguments

try
{
    var locationManager = new CLLocationManager();
    locationManager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();
    CLLocation currentLocation = locationManager.Location;
    if (currentLocation != null)
    {
        // Create EXIF metadata
        var metadata = new NSDictionary();
        var gpsMetadata = new NSDictionary();

        gpsMetadata[CGImageProperties.GPSLatitude] = NSNumber.FromDouble(currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude);
        NSObject nSObject = new NSObject();
        gpsMetadata[CGImageProperties.GPSLatitudeRef] = new NSString(currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude >= 0 ? "N" : "S");
        gpsMetadata[CGImageProperties.GPSLongitude] = NSNumber.FromDouble(currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude);
        gpsMetadata[CGImageProperties.GPSLongitudeRef] = new NSString(currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude >= 0 ? "E" : "W");

        metadata[CGImageProperties.GPSDictionary] = gpsMetadata;

        // Save the image with metadata
        var imageData = resultImage.AsJPEG();

        CGImageSource source = CGImageSource.FromData(imageData);
        CGImage cgImageTest = source.CreateImage(0, null);
        var uti = CGImageSource.TypeIdentifiers[0];
        var destinationData = new NSMutableData();
        var options = new CGImageDestinationOptions(metadata);
        using (var destination = CGImageDestination.Create(destinationData, uti, 1))
        {
            destination.AddImage(cgImageTest, options);
            destination.Close();
        }

        // Save the image to disk
        NSError error;
        destinationData.Save(fileName, false, out error);

        if (error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error saving image: {error.LocalizedDescription}");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error saving image: {ex.Message}");
}


use EXIF tags to add metadata to an image. There are numerous nuget packages to do this

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Does the error(Incorrect number or types of arguments) appear in a specific line of code? Is your MAUI version .net8?
